# Lowest value in a month using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am tryin to use python and pandas to simplify a task that we normally do in excel. So far I have combined two csv's into a single df and need some help going further. Anyways without going into to much detail on the specifics of my project using the following data frame I want to calculate the minimum elevation for a given month:

```
       Start               Minimum Z   Month    
0    2024-10-09 12:00:00  6056.483651  10/24 
1    2029-10-08 00:00:00  5450.000000  10/29 
2    2029-10-15 00:00:00  5450.000000  10/29 
3    2029-10-25 00:00:00  5435.000000  10/29 
4    2029-11-01 00:00:00  5450.000000  11/29
```

Now my goal is to take this data frame and calculate the min of the "Minimum Z" column for each month. So the output data frame would be this:

```
        Elevation  Month    
0      6056.483651  10/24 
1      5435.000000  10/29 
2      5450.000000  11/29
```

So the goal is to get the lowest elevation for each month in the data frame and populate a new data frame. I have searched for a while to see if someone has done something similar but I can't seem to find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby()` and `.min()`.

```py
df[['Month','Minimum Z']].groupby('Month').min()
```

This first selects just the two columns in the dataframe. Then the `.groupby()` groups things where we have a row/record for each unique value in the column in the groupby (so 'Month' here), and then it does the `.min()` on the other column (in this case, the 'Minimum Z'). If you wanted a sum of the aggregate column, you'd do `.sum()`, but that of course makes no sense with elevations.

If you want to rename the column then, just `df = df.rename(columns={'Minimum Z':'Elevation'})`

Comment: Deleted my previous comment because I am an idiot who didn't see "df" I accidentally copied 10 lines down....... This did exactly what I needed!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps. here you get a data frame with the minimum values for the month

```
df.merge(df.groupby('Month')['Z'].min().reset_index(), how='inner')
```

```
    Start   Minimum     Z   Month
0   2024-10-09  12:00:00    6056.483651     10/24
1   2029-10-25  00:00:00    5435.000000     10/29
2   2029-11-01  00:00:00    5450.000000     11/29
```

PS: in my copying of the dataframe, time end up being under column 'minimum',